# Memory leak when declaring string

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I'm working on a C++ console application that is required to have 0 memory leaks. However, I'm very new to memory leaks and I wonder why this is already causing a memory leak, while there is barely any code:

```
int main()
{
    std::string httpResult;


    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();


    return 0;
}
```

This is the given memory leak in VS 2019:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{93} normal block at 0x00000146FEB63BD0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 FB 15 D6 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

The only thing I'm doing is declaring a std::string. Why is that a memory leak?

Comment: That code doesn't compile at all.

Comment: I remember similar question, but dont find it anymore. `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` can only look for allocated memory that is not freed and report that as leak. Try `{ std::string httpResult; }  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`

Comment: Print the address of the string.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code definitely compiles. You'll have to include <crtdbg.h> and <iostream>.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thank you. That works! No more memory leaks. So the point is to just put your code in an empty body (with curly brackets) inside main?

Comment: @M.A you mean when I debug?

Comment: @TristanvO The put that there, it matters. `#include <iostram>` introduces at least 3 singleton objects `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::cerr`.

Comment: If you don't know that std::string requires <iostream>, then you're not capable of helping me with this question either.Therefore, absolutely no problem if I forget to add the includes in this example.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the comment. The includes are relevant for your question because similar to your string the headers you include come with objects that are not destroyed yet when you check for leaks. I wouldnt be surprised if `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` has some mechanism to be aware of those globals, but nevertheless the includes are very relevant for the question ( I suppose πάνταῥεῖ knows that `std::string` requires to include `<string>`, not `<iostream>` !, and not posting the same code that you compile always is a problem imho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:

```
int main()
{
    std::string httpResult;


    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    std::abort();

    return 0;
}
```

This code has a memory leak, because on calling `abort` destructors of objects with automatic storage duration are not called. `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` cannot look ahead to know if resources **will** be cleaned up after it is called. There is no memory leak in this code

```
int main()
{
 
    {
        std::string httpResult;
    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();


    return 0;
}
```

(and `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` does not see any candidates for a memory leak.)

Comment: Thank you! But is std::abort() required? Without calling abort, I get 0 memory leaks too. As long as I put the string in an empty body.

Comment: @TristanvO sorry the `std::abort` was only as an example to show that the memory of `httpResult` can leak. I removed it from the "correct" snippet

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I understand now